# How to 'href' to the element even to the top margin of each div?

Tags: html, css

The following is html code I have written to store some of my favorite gradients and I wanted to link anchor to 'id="grad1"' and 'id="grad2"' even including the margin at the top.

I thought the ':target:before' would work to provide the margin when those 'id's were targeted but that does not work for me somehow.

When I link to the below html, it only links to the top of the content, not to the top of the margin of each div.

Please correct me on any of my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Gradation</title>
    <style> 
        body {
            background-color: white;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        div {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            margin-top: 200px;
            margin-bottom: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
        }

        :target:before {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            height: 200px;
            margin-top: -200px;
        }

        span {
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 50px;
            font-weight: 900;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            margin-top: 190px;
        }

        #grad1 {
            margin-top: 200px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff9a9e 0%, #fad0c4 99%, #fad0c4 100%);
        }

        #grad2 {
            background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #a18cd1 0%, #fbc2eb 100%);
        }
    
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="grad1"><span>1. warm flame</span></div>
    <div id="grad2"><span>2. night fade</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The following is another html code that will link to the above html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Gradation</title>
    <style>
         body {
            width: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        div {
            width: 45%;
            display: inline-block;
            list-style: none;
            font-family: offside;
            font-size: 50px;
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 90px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            margin: 30px auto;
        }

        #grad1 {
            background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff9a9e 0%, #fad0c4 99%, #fad0c4 100%);
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        }

        #grad1:hover {
            color: white;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff9a9e 0%, #fad0c4 99%, #fad0c4 100%);
        }

        #grad2 {
            background: linear-gradient(to top, #a18cd1 0%, #fbc2eb 100%);
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        }

        #grad2:hover {
            color: white;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background: linear-gradient(to top, #a18cd1 0%, #fbc2eb 100%);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div><a href="radial-position.html#grad1" target="_blank" id="grad1">1. warm flame</a></div>
    <div><a href="radial-position.html#grad2" target="_blank" id="grad2">2. night fade</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `scroll-margin-top` to each of your `grad`s that is equal to the margin you apply.

Example:

```
#grad1 {
  margin-top: 200px;
  scroll-margin-top: 200px;
}
```

This way, anchors will scroll to the offset specified by the `scroll-margin-top` instead of the element `border`.

Answer (score 0):

With your sample, on firefox 74, anchors are functional.

Still the second anchor "2. NIGHT FADE" : **because we reach the end of page**, the anchor does not link to the top div. But that's only for the second one.

If you want to solve : you have to add more margin at bottom of your divs.